# Não consigo executar o laço jquerry

Tags: javascript, jquery, loop, for, chartjs

Preciso criar um laço para que o msm alimente um gráfico.

```
while($(".previsto").eq(0).text(),){}
```

Preciso pegar esses valores eq(0), eq(1), eq(2)...

```
$(".previsto").eq(0).text(),
$(".previsto").eq(1).text(),
$(".previsto").eq(2).text(),
```

...

Comment: Por que tem uma vírgula depois do `.text()`?

Comment: Porque isso é pra gerar o gráfico, por isso precisa da vírgular, quero criar um laço para q isso fique dinamico. O eq() é como se fosse um índice

Comment: Estou tentando algo do tipo :

Comment: for(var i = i; i < ($(".previsto").eq(0).text()).length; i++){
           console.log($(".previsto").eq(0).text());
        }

Comment: Armazenei o resultado de uma Consulta em divs dentro de um laço no php, preciso pegar os valores dessas divs, por isso o seletor é uma "." class. Preciso de um laço para pegar os valores da div " $(".previsto").eq(0).text();" usando essa função eq()

Comment: Tenta assim: `for(var i = 0; i < $(".previsto").length ; i++){ console.log($(".previsto").eq(i).text()); }`

Comment: Nossa parceiro, funcionou. Mt obrigado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pra pegar os índices dos elementos (do primeiro ao último), a variável do laço deve começar em `0` até o número dos elementos -1:

```
for(var i = 0; i < $(".previsto").length; i++){ 
    console.log($(".previsto").eq(i).text());
}
```

O `$(".previsto").length` retorna o número de elementos com a classe `.previsto`, e a variável `i` deve iniciar de `0` até enquanto for menor que `$(".previsto").length`.